# execute a c prog in background through shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, background-process

I want to run a c prog in background using shell script and once the prog starts running in background my shell script should continue to run without waiting for the c prog to end.
I am using ampersand '&' for the same but it my script still waits for the c prog to end.

Please help.

This is my script.

s1.sh

```
. /s2.sh

func1
pid=run_mem_eater_prog
func2 $pid
```

s2.sh

```
run_mem_eater_prog() {     
     ./mem_eater&  
     curr_pid=$!
     echo $curr_pid
     return $curr_pid
}
```

When I run s1.sh, func1 gets executed then "run_mem_eater_prog" is called 
which executes ./mem_eater (c executable) and the scripts waits for it to get finished and then calls func2.

How to call func2 without waiting for mem_eater to finish?

Comment: What is `func1` and `func2`? The `pid` variable in `sh2.sh` will be set to the string `run_mem_eater_prog`, but it will _not_ call the `run_mem_eater_prog` shell function. Use `pid=$(run_mem_eater_prog)` for that.

Comment: sorry for the typo. I am calling it as pid=$(run_mem_eater_prog).

Comment: In func2 I have to use the pid returned and write it into sys/fs/cgroups/memory/tasks. ./mem_eater is a c prog which does some malloc and memset in a continuous loop(50 times). Problem is, my script waits for this ./mem_eater to get finished and then runs func2,  by the time $pid is passed to func2 as prog already ended i get an error of no such process exists.

Comment: It's not that the `mem_eater` program actually has time to finish and exit before `func2` is called? Allocating memory 50 times may be a quick operation.

Comment: I have added a delay of 1 sec for every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
( ./mem_eater & )
```